# How to automate selection of type of installation by editing Isolinux?

Tags: debian, debian-installer, headless

I'm trying to fully automate the process of Debian 9 installation, by using a preseed config file. The OS will be installed inside a VM on a remote headless server.

The only step which still requires user interaction is the main menu of the installer when I have to select the type of installation. See picture:
[image]

So how do I automatically select one of the options here? Specifically I want to select `Advanced options`, and then `Automated install`. I think by editing the `isolinux` files, I should get there, but I don't quite understand these files. According to this [article](https://sowhatisthesolution.wordpress.com/2016/03/13/headless-debian-install-via-ssh/) I modified the following isolinux files like this:

gtk.cfg

```
label installgui
    menu label ^Graphical install
    kernel /install.amd/vmlinuz
    append vga=788 initrd=/install.amd/gtk/initrd.gz --- quiet
```

adtxt.cfg

```
default auto
label expert
    menu label E^xpert install
    kernel /install.amd/vmlinuz
    append priority=low vga=788 initrd=/install.amd/initrd.gz --- 
include rqtxt.cfg
label auto
    menu label ^Automated install
    menu default
    kernel /install.amd/vmlinuz
    append auto=true priority=critical vga=788 initrd=/install.amd/initrd.gz --- quiet
```

But nothing changed. The cursor was still on the Graphical install, and I cannot afford user interaction.
Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autoselect keyword did not work for me, but I'm using Debian 10 so meh. I just changed the line in isolinux.cfg:

```
default vesamenu.c32
```

to

```
default install
```

The generic form is

```
default <label string for the entry you want>
```

You can look around in the isolinux/*.cfg files for the entry you want to boot, then grab the string after "label" for that one, and put it as the default in isolinux.cfg

Interestingly, the "install" entry will try and use a preseed file if it can find one. So minimal other changes for an auto install on Debian 10.

Comment: This is actually a much cleaner solution, and it works like a charm. I used `default auto`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this with the help of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/379761/install-linux-alternative-os-on-headless-server) thread.

I changed `gtk.cfg` to:

```
default auto
label installgui
    menu label ^Graphical install
    menu default
    kernel /install.amd/vmlinuz
    append vga=788 initrd=/install.amd/gtk/initrd.gz --- quiet 
label auto
    menu label ^Automated install
    menu default
    kernel /install.amd/vmlinuz
    append auto=true priority=critical vga=788 initrd=/install.amd/initrd.gz --- quiet
```

Then I increased timeout in `prompt.cfg` and `isolinux.cfg` from 0 to 4, like: `timeout 4`.
Lastly I appended `autoselect auto` to `isolinux.cfg` file.